# Installed nuget packages in Visual Studio 2019 project checkbox unchecked

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I am trying to create a packages file for the project & noticed that installed nuget packages in Visual Studio 2019 have got the project box unchecked.
I am positive that I am using these packages in the project.

For instance I am using the Entity Framework for the data access & update. I have ensured that all the packages are still being used in the project & the `packages.config` file has got all the packages listed in it.

[Visual Studio ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxJyZ.png)

Comment: Why do you want the check box checked in Project column? When a version is showed under Version column, you know the packages are installed. Maybe you are not quite familiar with the NuGet dialog design.

Comment: Just as Lex said, it is just designed by that and it is used to perform some operation to this nuget packages.

Comment: Thanks Perry Qian-MSFT & Lex Li.I was under the impression that the project using the packages would be automatically selected, I would be using the check boxes for nuget packages operations only.

Answer (score 0):

> Installed nuget packages in Visual Studio 2019 project checkbox
>   unchecked

The window which you provided actually does not actually work as you described. **And it is just designed by that.**

What you need to note is that the projects that can be displayed on this window, such as `2020Portal.Data`, `2020Portal.Mailbox`, etc., have already installed the nuget package  `Entity Framework`. Only projects that already have the nuget package installed can be displayed in this window. That's why they show up there.

**And** the **checkbox** functionality is only intended to enable the selected items to perform **uninstall** or **update** the nuget `Entity Framework`. It's just for the convenience of choosing certain operations to perform.

[image]

Hope it could help you.